# how can we log bot and user conversation messages in azure sql database?

Tags: c#, logging, botframework

I have created a bot in  microsoft botframework sdk v4  using c# and it is working well. Now I want to log those conversation messages in to an azure sql database. How can I do this??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

In Bot Builder V4, [ITranscriptLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptlogger) has replaced IActivityLogger.

You can find an Entity Framework implementation here: https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity/botbuilder-community-dotnet/pull/78

You can create an **ITranscriptLogger** implementation that connects to sql server and persist any fields you want from the Activity in [LogActivityAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.itranscriptlogger.logactivityasync)

```cs
    // Summary:
    //     Transcript logger stores activities for conversations for recall.
    public interface ITranscriptLogger
    {
        // Summary:
        //     Log an activity to the transcript.
        //
        // Parameters:
        //   activity:
        //     The activity to transcribe.
        //
        // Returns:
        //     A task that represents the work queued to execute.
        Task LogActivityAsync(IActivity activity);
    }
```

Once you have an ITranscriptLogger implementation, it can be added to the Middleware stack in Startup.cs with:

```cs
var myLogger = new MyTranscriptLogger(Configuration.GetSection("BotDataConnectionString").Value);
var transcriptMiddleware = new TranscriptLoggerMiddleware(myLogger);
options.Middleware.Add(transcriptMiddleware);
```